# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de editar el header y el footer en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Quiero modificar el Footer y el Header de mi sitio hecho con WordPress, agregando uno más profesional. Lo puedo hacer a través de un plugin, pero quiero saber si es mejor hacerlo así o creando un tema hijo, desde su experiencia ¿qué es mejor? ¿existen otros métodos?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: child theme y editar header.php / footer.php te da mas libertad de acción y no dependes de tener un plugin actualizado

Answer (score 1):

Usa el plugin code snippets es mas facil implementar pequeños cambios en el codigo y los cambios se guardan en el plugin y no en el childtheme y si despues quieres modificar algo no tienes que estar modificando nada en el servidor solo desde el plugin, a mi parecer usar un childtheme en lugar de snippets es como hacer una segunda casa solo para cambiar una ventana o la puerta, si los cambios van a ser muchos si seria mejor un childtheme